# R within group sum of squares kmeans

Tags: r, statistics, k-means

I have the following code, which is giving me the an error:

```
# Read input dataset from CSV file
input_dataset <-     
read.csv("C:\\Users\\sw029693\\Desktop\\Overtime_work_hrs_analytics\\input_dataset.csv", header = TRUE)

wss <- (nrow(input_dataset)-1)*sum(apply(input_dataset,2,var))
```

which gives the following error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
4: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
5: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion

> wss
[1] NA

> colnames(input_dataset)
[1] "client"            "domain"            "user_name"             
"cdf_display"       "position"          "shift_start"      
[7] "shift_end"         "shift_length_avg"  "patients_seen_cnt"
```

It looks like the wss is NA, I am not sure why. Any ideas?

Comment: NA's in your data? Have you looked? Seriously, walk before you can run. Always check your data is what you think it is when you read it in before you try doing any maths on it. Check columns are numbers. Check for missing values. Check it, write a function to check it, then write a function to check that function.

Answer (score 0):

K-means only supports numerical data.

You columns `user_name` etc. probably are not numerical.

Bring your data into the appropriate format first.